# I'm running fsck and getting "ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block"

Tags: fsck

I'm running:
 `fsck -n /dev/sdb2` 
 and I'm getting:

```
fsck from util-linux 2.31.1
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
fsck.ext2: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdb2

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>
```

Any advice? **What's wrong with the partition and what should I do about it??**

Additional information, as requested:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

outputs:

```
Device        Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1  32335872 60061695 27725824 13.2G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdb2      2048     4095     2048    1M BIOS boot
/dev/sdb3      4096   503807   499712  244M EFI System
/dev/sdb4    503808  4610047  4106240    2G Linux filesystem
/dev/sdb5   4610048 32335871 27725824 13.2G Linux filesystem
```

Comment: Well, is the filesystem of sdb2 ext2/3/4 ?

Comment: @JohnRonald The filesystem of sdb2 is **ext4**

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo fdisk -l`.

Comment: @heynnema: Done.

Comment: @heynnema: So, `fsck` is good only for Linux filesystem?

Comment: Yes. Tell me what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: I was trying to back up USB stick using Clonezilla and I thought I have to run fsck on all partition to make sure that there is no problem.

Comment: Clonezilla might not be the best way to back up a USB stick. Why are you trying to do that? `dd` might be a better tool. Type `man dd` for more info. BE CAREFUL... if you give an incorrect `dd` command you could wipe out the wrong disk.

Comment: @heynnema: I was advised to use Clonezilla for backup, that's why I'm using Clonezilla.

Comment: Clonezilla won't clone anything to a smaller destination (even smaller by only 1 block). Why are you trying to back up a USB stick?

Comment: @heynnema: I'm trying to back up a USB stick, because it has all the system files and data on it. I'm running Ubuntu live with persistent storage from that USB stick.

Comment: Generally not a good idea to try and run a live system from a USB stick. Performance and space issues are a problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're doing the `fsck` on the wrong partition (sdb2).

`sudo fdisk -l` shows us that the following partitions are "Linux filesystem"...

```
/dev/sdb4    503808  4610047  4106240    2G Linux filesystem
/dev/sdb5   4610048 32335871 27725824 13.2G Linux filesystem
```

Here are the commands that you should be using...

Boot to Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in "Try Ubuntu" mode.

Open the `terminal` application and type:

```
sudo fsck -f /dev/sdb4
sudo fsck -f /dev/sdb5
reboot
```