# Ubuntu 18.04 boot error

Tags: boot

I built a computer with an Aeorus B450x, Ryzen 3 2200G CPU with an integrated Vega 8 GPU, 2 x 8G RAM, and a 500GB SSD. The OS is Ubuntu 18.04. I've mostly used it for gaming via the Steam client. It has worked without issue until now.

It was in standby for a few hours today and when I entered my password to do some work nothing happened. I could move the cursor and enter characters, it just wouldn't open. When I reset the machine it froze on the Ubuntu loading screen. Now it either freezes on the loading screen or goes to black. I can boot from a USB though.

I had been learning to code Arduino before it went into standby. A SkillShare video was queued and Tinkercad circuits was open (I was simulating a circuit) in another window. I'm assuming that those programs running when it went into standby somehow caused an issue with the GPU, but I have played Boarder lands 2 on near maximum settings, so I don't know how those two windows could freeze the machine or why rebooting wouldn't solve the issue. When I boot from the USB the machine seems to run fine.

I held left Shift when booting, the screen went to black and I  pressed Alt+ left arrow and saw an error with the GPU. I'm on my phone now, but I took a picture of the errors and copied the text and pasted it below. It seems like the error happens at different time during the boot process.

```
1 Stopped GNOME Display Manager.

Starting Detect the available GPUs and deal with any system changes...

.833734) blk_update_request: critical medium error, deu numeon1, sector 433668392 op .8502581 blk_update_request: critical medium error, deu numeon1, sector 433668392 op

.9748281 blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev numeon1, sector 433668392 op .9913341 blk_update_request: critical medium error, deu numeon1, sector 433668392 op

.1178231 blk_update_request: critical medium error, deu nume@n1, sector 433668392 1349901 blk_update_request: critical medium error, deu numeon1, sector 433668392 op

op

.2573261 blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev numeon1, sector 433668392 op

.2741211 blk_update_request: critical medium error, deu numeon1, sector 433668392 op

.3960813 blk_update_request: critical medium error, deu numeOn1, sector 433668392 op ( .4125801 blk_update_request: critical medium error, deu numeOn1, sector 433668392 op ( 1 Started Detect the available GPUs and deal with any system changes.

Starting GNOME Display Manager... 1 Started GNOME Display Manager.

Starting Accounts Service... Starting Authorization Manager...

DJ Failed to start Authorization Manager. systemctl status polkit.service for details.

1 Started Accounts Service.

1 Stopped GNOME Display Manager. Starting Detect the available GPUs and deal with any system changes...

.0833320 bik_update_request: critical medium error, deu numeon1, sector 433668392

op 0

.099823) blk_update_request: critical medium error, deu numeon1, sector 433668392 op 0 221273] blk_update_request: critical medium error, deu numeOn1, sector 433668392 op 0

.2384171 blk_update_request: critical medium error, deu numeOn1, sector 433668392 op 0 3669041 blk_update_request: critical medium error, deu numeon1, sector 433668392 op 0

.3837331 blk_update_request: critical medium error, deu numeon1, sector 433668392 op 0: .511149) blk_update_request: critical medium error, deu numeOn1, sector 433668392 op 0

.5276221 blk_update_request: critical medium error, deu numeOn1, sector 433668392 op 0 .651289) blk_update_request: critical medium error, deu nume@n1, sector 433668392 op 0 .667730) blk_update_request: critical medium error, deu numeon1, sector 433668392 op 0>

1 Started Detect the available CPUS and deal With an system changes
```

---

Fdisk command as requested:

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/loop0: 1.9 GiB, 1987817472 bytes, 3882456 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop1: 88.5 MiB, 92778496 bytes, 181208 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop2: 54.4 MiB, 57069568 bytes, 111464 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop3: 42.8 MiB, 44879872 bytes, 87656 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop4: 149.9 MiB, 157184000 bytes, 307000 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop5: 4 MiB, 4218880 bytes, 8240 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop6: 14.8 MiB, 15462400 bytes, 30200 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop7: 1008 KiB, 1032192 bytes, 2016 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: E0D5BD46-7C96-4F9D-9678-D2250E4AEC0D

Device           Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1    2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2 1050624 976771071 975720448 465.3G Linux filesystem

Disk /dev/sda: 7.5 GiB, 8004304896 bytes, 15633408 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x68f2002a

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *     2048 15633407 15631360  7.5G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)

Disk /dev/loop8: 3.7 MiB, 3825664 bytes, 7472 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

---

This is what happens when I try an alternate block:

ubuntu@ubuntu:-$ sudo e2fsck -b 32768 /dev/nvmeOn1 e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)

e2fsck: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/nvnen1

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4

filesystem. If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:

e2fsck -b 8193  or

e2fsck -b 32768

Found a gpt partition table in /dev/nvme0n1

---

Smartctl output as requested:

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo smartctl -a /dev/nvme0n1
smartctl 6.6 2016-05-31 r4324 [x86_64-linux-5.0.0-23-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, [www.smartmontools.org](http://www.smartmontools.org)

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Number:                       CT500P1SSD8
Serial Number:                      1940E222A6B5
Firmware Version:                   P3CR013
PCI Vendor/Subsystem ID:            0xc0a9
IEEE OUI Identifier:                0x00a075
Controller ID:                      1
Number of Namespaces:               1
Namespace 1 Size/Capacity:          500,107,862,016 [500 GB]
Namespace 1 Formatted LBA Size:     512
Local Time is:                      Thu Feb  4 13:19:36 2021 UTC
Firmware Updates (0x14):            2 Slots, no Reset required
Optional Admin Commands (0x0016):   Format Frmw_DL *Other*
Optional NVM Commands (0x005e):     Wr_Unc DS_Mngmt Wr_Zero Sav/Sel_Feat *Other*
Maximum Data Transfer Size:         32 Pages
Warning  Comp. Temp. Threshold:     70 Celsius
Critical Comp. Temp. Threshold:     80 Celsius

Supported Power States
St Op     Max   Active     Idle   RL RT WL WT  Ent_Lat  Ex_Lat
0 +     9.00W       -        -    0  0  0  0        5       5
1 +     4.60W       -        -    1  1  1  1       30      30
2 +     3.80W       -        -    2  2  2  2       30      30
3 -   0.0500W       -        -    3  3  3  3     1000    1000
4 -   0.0040W       -        -    4  4  4  4     6000    8000

Supported LBA Sizes (NSID 0x1)
Id Fmt  Data  Metadt  Rel_Perf
0 +     512       0         0

=== START OF SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

SMART/Health Information (NVMe Log 0x02, NSID 0x1)
Critical Warning:                   0x00
Temperature:                        35 Celsius
Available Spare:                    100%
Available Spare Threshold:          10%
Percentage Used:                    0%
Data Units Read:                    116,491,813 [59.6 TB]
Data Units Written:                 1,678,571 [859 GB]
Host Read Commands:                 757,713,041
Host Write Commands:                25,945,048
Controller Busy Time:               2,017
Power Cycles:                       50
Power On Hours:                     9,524
Unsafe Shutdowns:                   26
Media and Data Integrity Errors:    43,137
Error Information Log Entries:      0
Warning  Comp. Temperature Time:    0
Critical Comp. Temperature Time:    0
Temperature Sensor 1:               35 Celsius
Temperature Sensor 2:               35 Celsius
Temperature Sensor 5:               43 Celsius

Read Error Information Log failed: NVMe Status 0x02

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu has a problem with your block device aka Harddisk.

This seems to be a severe error, so I'd grab an USB with a live cd, boot into your PC and check your hard drives.
First try to "fix" the partitions using `e2fsck -f -y -v /dev/sdXX` (like /dev/sda1, depends on your system)

If done use **smartctl** to check about the health of that device

**Update**
To list all devices you should execute `fdisk -l` (the l stands for list and is NOT a 1)

It seems that the superblock is broken and needs to be fixed. But:

/dev/sda is your usb stick, do not work with that device!
So `efsck dev/sda` will not work.

It looks like you are having a nvme drive:

> Disk /dev/nvme0n1p1

So you'll have to work on this drive....

Comment: I have lost the option to boot from USB device. It also boots to a black screen with one underscore before it goes to BIOS, which is new. I can fire up the old laptop to try and get a new version of Ubuntu on the flash drive. Will that potentially corrupt the laptop though?

Comment: Ok. Running from flashdrive now. I checked the filesystem on both partitions and they are undamaged.

Comment: I ran e2fsck and got:.

ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block e2fsck: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...

e2fsck: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/nvmen1 The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystem. If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock: e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
or
e2fsck -b 32768 <device>
Found a gpt partition table in /dev/nvmen1

Comment: Well, it seems you found your problem. `fsck` might be able to fix it. Check the manual. If my answer helped you, I'd appreciate if you'd "accept" it

Comment: On a second thought: please show us the result of `fdisk -l`, paste the result into your answer. And paste the complete command you've executed.

Comment: It still won't boot. Using the alternate super block didn't work. I stepped away from it for a bit. Fresh eyes see better. I'll run and post that command now.

Comment: See my updated answer. ***You did not execute the correct command for fdisk.*** And you did not show your efsck  command - what exactly did you type in?

Comment: I see. I misread that command. I'll run it again. The command I entered to fix the block was. e2fsck -b 32768 /dev/nvme0n1. That didn't work so I ran  the same command with /dev/nvme0n1p1. With both of the backup blocks that listed(32768 and 8193). I really appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: Delete your old fdisk -l output and replace it with the correct one. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1188297/im-running-fsck-and-getting-ext2fs-open2-bad-magic-number-in-super-block) why I need that data.

Comment: Last not least (you've probably didn't read it above) execute `smartctl -a /dev/nvme0n1`  and paste the results.

Comment: I ran fdisk -l and posted it. I pasted to a txt file and sent it to the phone via bluetooth. It seems odd that bluetooth works and wifi doesn't even though they're on the same card. Anyway, I have to download and install smartctl which I can't do until I figure out/fix the internet connection. I'll run the command and post it as soon as I do. Thanks again for helping. I'm learning a lot.

Comment: You have to work on `/dev/nvme0n1p1` - this drive seems to be broken

Comment: I edited with the smartctl output. I think I had just run an update and restarted the day before I had the problem. Could it be that something went wrong in the update?