# Broken Xubuntu installation in HP Compaq 6720s

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, xubuntu

I was trying to install Xubuntu 22.04.2 in an old HP Compaq 6720s along with Windows.

I chose "Try Xubuntu" option, and then opened the Xubuntu installer. During the installation, I noticed HDD partitions were constantly mounted automatically by some reason but I unmounted them before continuing the process.

I chose automatic installation instead of manually partitioning the disk.

The installation process went smooth until I noticed that it got stuck. The installer console said:

```
/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/frontend/gtk_components/nmwidgets.py:18: Warning: Source ID 23807 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self.timeout_id)
```

as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1240997/slow-ubuntu-20-04-installation-warning-source-id-xxxx-was-not-found-when-attem).

I interrupted the installation and shut down the computer. After booting again from the live image, I could see the GRUB menu and select "Try or Install Xubuntu" but then the screen remained black and got stuck.

Trying to boot into Windows does not work anymore and the error `No system disk or disk error, replace and strike any key when ready` appears.

I tried to boot with a Kali Linux image and again GRUB was loaded but after choosing "Try or Install" the system got stuck and I had to hard reboot.

I guess in the first installation try the installer messed up the disk partitions or maybe had I/O problems, although that can not explain why now live images are not working.

Now I ended up with an unusable PC and have no idea how to solve it. Could it be problems with RAM? Should I try to fix the HDD from BIOS? What tests can be performed?

EDIT: I managed to boot from Kali live in failsafe mode and ran fsck on the HDD with the following results:

```
$ sudo fsck -y /dev/sda
fsck from util-linux 2.38.1
e2fsck 1.47.0 (5-Feb-2023)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
fsck.ext2: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sda

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I'm running fsck and getting "ext2fs\_open2: Bad magic number in super-block"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1188297/im-running-fsck-and-getting-ext2fs-open2-bad-magic-number-in-super-block)